# converting a keras DirectoryIterator to a torch variable

Tags: deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am creating a classifier using PyTorch for classifying a dog and cat. My question is that I only have 10000 images for cats and dogs, 8000 for training and 2000 for testing. So to prevent overfitting I want to use keras's ImageDataGenerator function to generator augmented images. This is what I did for that portion

```
 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, #corresponds to rescaling pixel values of the images, rescales the image so that the pixels have values between 0 and 1
                                   shear_range = 0.2, #corresponds to shearing to the images
                                   zoom_range = 0.2, #corresponds to a random zoom on the images
                                   horizontal_flip = True) #filps the images horizontally

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) #preprocessing the images of the test set

#since our images are formatted in a certain way we use the flow_from_directory() function
 #Creating the training set
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64), 
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

#Creating the test set
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode ='binary')
```

Now the only problem is that I need the training_set and test_set to be converted to Torch Variables, but right now there DirectoryIterators. So is there a way to convert the training_set and test_set to Torch Variables. Or can I do the same thing that I did here but using pytorch.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following example, I think it will give you some further clarification on how to implement data augmentation with PyTorch:

https://github.com/jiangqy/Data-Augmentation-Pytorch